# How to handle erros and show up only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating form, it gets called everytime whem i click on submit and it displays those errors all the time, so is this a bad whay to handle errors? And how to change the code, that it will show only one time, those errors ?

```
<a href="#" onclick="validateForm() ? window.document.forms[0].submit() : false"  id="submit">Sūtīt &rarr;</a>
```

Js file

```
window.onload = function() {
null;
}

function renderErrors(errors) {
for (var i=0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    $("#errors").append("<div> &raquo; " + errors[i] + "</div>");
};
}

function validateForm() {
result = true;
var errors = [];

if (document.getElementById("full-name").value == '') {
    errors.push("Lauks 'Vārs, Uzvārds' ir jānorāda obligāti");
    result = false;
}
if (document.getElementById("telefonanr").value == '') {
    errors.push("Lauks 'Telefona numurs' ir jānorāda obligāti");
    result = false;
}
if (document.getElementById("zinojums").value == '') {
    errors.push("Lauks 'Ziņojums' ir jānorāda obligāti");
    result = false;
}

if (errors[0] == undefined) {
    return true;
} else {
    renderErrors(errors);
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line

```
  $("#errors").html('');
```

just before

```
   $("#errors").append("<div> &raquo; " + errors[i] + "</div>");
```

Like:

```
   $("#errors").html('');
   $("#errors").append("<div> &raquo; " + errors[i] + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `renderErrors` function to empty the contents before you append.

```
function renderErrors(errors) {
  var container = $('#errors');
  container.empty();
  for (var i=0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    container.append("<div> &raquo; " + errors[i] + "</div>");
  };
}
```